# Django allauth: empty 'signup_url'

Tags: django, django-allauth

Using django 1.8.16 and package django-allauth==0.27.0

Login works fine, but signup page cannot be reached from login page.

The default login template 'login.html' contains a link to a signup page:

```
<p>{% blocktrans %}If you have not created an account yet, then please
<a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a> first.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
```

But since the value of 'signup_url' is empty, this points nowhere.

**Question is: where should 'signup_url' get its value from?**

django-allauth documentation doesn't mention this:
http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

More info:

- 'mysite.com/user/login'  works fine
- 'mysite.com/accounts/signup'  actually shows the signup page, so this is what 'signup_url' should refer to
- Django debug toolbar doesn't work on this page, as one needs to be logged in for the toolbar to work?

Settings extract:

```
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('logout')
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
    r'^about$',
    r'^accounts/password/reset/$',
    r'^accounts/signup/$',
)
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
```

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by wrong url settings.

Working top level urls.py section:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```