# Django allauth: empty 'signup_url, login_url and logout_url'

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Using django 1.11.4 and package django-allauth==0.33.0

Login works fine

The default login template 'login.html' contains a link to a signup page:

```
<p>{% blocktrans %}If you have not created an account yet, then please
<a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a> first.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
```

and that works fine but any other page then /accounts/* its just empty

base.html:

```
 <div class="nav-wrapper">
                      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">

                             {% if user.is_authenticated %}


                            <li>  Welcome: {% user_display user %}</li>
                            <li><a href="{{ logout_url }}">logout</a></li>

                            {% else %}
                            <li><a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        <li></li>

                      </ul>
                    </div>
```

I use the base.html on /accounts/* as well as on the index.
on /accounts/* its works fine but on the index the {{ logout_url }} etc are empty.

Settings extract:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

[Same problem answer didnt help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277989/django-allauth-empty-signup-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logout page appears after {% if user.is_authenticated %}. This means that if the user is not authenticated, your logout page and others that falls into the "if statement" will not show.

If you want it to show, delete {% if user.is_authenticated %}